# Convert a .bbl file to a .bib file

Tags: latex, file-converter, bibtex

I am looking for a program or web service that can convert a .bbl file to a .bib file. Any OS/license/price is fine.

I am aware that some information may be missing in the resulting .bib file, which may require some manual post-processing, but that would still be better performing the entire conversion manually.

---

I tried [AMS' MRef](http://www.ams.org/mref) as well as [text2bib](http://text2bib.economics.utoronto.ca/) but these tools expect the references as listed in the final documents, not the .bbl file itself

Examples of references that are correctly converted by these two tools:

```
Arrow, K. J., L. Hurwicz, and H. Uzawa (1961), "Constraint qualifications in maximization problems," Naval Research Logistics Quarterly 8, 175-191.
Arrow, K. J., L. Hurwicz, and H. Uzawa [1961], ``Constraint qualifications in maximization problems,'' {\it Naval Research Logistics Quarterly}, 8(2), 175-191.
```

The "best" method I found so far is parsing the bbl to extract the title and authors, then use AHK/Sikuli/Selenium to query Google Scholar and retrieve the bibtex from it.